# Is it possible to do a PhD with a Professor Emeritus?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, etiquette, professor-emeritus

The professor I want to work with for my PhD has recently changed status to `Professor Emeritus`. Would it still, in principle, be possible to do my PhD under his supervision or this just not possible?

Could I just email him and ask whether he still supervises PhD dissertations?

Or this regarded rude? I am not sure what exactly it means to be Emeritus I am afraid. How would I go about this?

Comment: You can find the answer here http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56035/any-experience-in-working-with-aged-emeritus-supervisors

Comment: If you are asking in terms of still seeking admission to the department, other than asking him directly (you might not get a response) you can also ask the graduate admissions coordinator, in the context of wanting to know if it is still possible to work with that person and thus naming them in your application, or if you'll need to find someone else. Determining mere possibility will vary by person and department (they may no longer have funding and stopped grant writing some time ago), but you can ask.

Comment: Of course you can try emailing him.  You might want to check with the department as well to find out if it would permit an emeritus to be the official advisor.

Comment: It should be clear to an aspiring academic that this question is impossible to answer without knowing what country, what kind of faculty, what kind of phd program, what kind of position the prof has/had, etc.

Comment: I would just ask him.